# Bzr gui commit tool - is one there?

Tags: version-control, commit, bazaar, pre-commit

Is there a gui commit tool for **bzr**, similar to **git gui**? The most important feature for me would be ability to break edits into separate commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QBzr/Bazaar Explorer should be part of the downloadable binaries (or can be installed as plugins, though that may require installing Qt and PyQt first).

The commands you're looking for are `qcommit`, `qshelve`, and `qunshelve`. The `qcommit` command allows you to select which files to commit, but like `commit` does not allow you to selectively commit only individual hunks within a file. Conversely, `qshelve`, like `shelve`, allows you to shelve changes at a finer granularity (i.e., individual hunks). Shelving can be reverted with `qunshelve` or `unshelve` commands.